# Android Edit WebView History

Tags: android, android-webview, browser-history

I have a sub-classed `WebView` and use it to go to an external site.I want to be able to selectively edit the list of history items stored by the `WebView`. I do not want to simply clear the history, or just override navigation (`.goBack()`, `.goForward()`, etc).

I could not find any way of doing this from `WebView`'s public methods. Am I missing something?

BTW, I also have a sub-classed `WebViewClient` and `WebChromeClient` if they are of any use.

Comment: "Am I missing something?" -- probably not. The history is what it is. If you need a filtered view of that history, you are on your own. `WebView` does not use the history itself, AFAIK, except to support methods like `goBack()` and `goForward()`.

Comment: About what I figured. I am probably stuck with manipulating history through back/forward operations, just hoping for something cleaner.

Comment: Hello! You found any way to edit history?